# How to map double related objects in entity framework, i.e. defining two FKs between the same entities

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have table `User` and one more table `ProfileView`.
They are in one to many relation.
I have a problem to create a reference between those tables via code first.
PageView looks like this:

```
public class ProfileView
    {
        public int ProfileViewId { get; set; }
        public int ViewedWho { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ViewedWhoUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime ViewDate{get;set;}
        public int ViewedBy { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ViewedByUser { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see there are two references from `User` to `ProfileView` how can I map this objects?
Right now EF auto gerate some keys with underscore not the one I created in boject.

Additionaly when I creating related object do I actually need to have something like `ICollection<ProfileView> ...` in related `User` object?
I have tried to map it like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(m => m.WhoViewedMyProfile)
                .WithMany(m => m.WhosProfileIViewed)
                .Map(x => x.MapLeftKey("UserId")
                    .MapRightKey("ViewedWho")
                    .ToTable("ViewedBy"));
```

But all I get is this:
[image]

ApplicationUser.cs has:

```
public ICollection<ApplicationUser> WhoViewedMyProfile { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> WhosProfileIViewed { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to do it:

1. using attributes
2. using Fluent API
3. using conventions (not for this case)

*NOTE: repeat for both properties*

With attributes, you simply have to add [ForeignKey attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
[ForeignKey("ViewedWho")]
public virtual ApplicationUser ViewedWhoUser { get; set; }
```

With Fluent API, you need to configure it like this: override the `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)` method, and configure the relation like this:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<ProfileView>
    .HasRequired(pv => pv.ViewedWhoUser) // or HasOptional
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeingKey(pv => pv.ViewedWho);
```

**This works when there is only one realtion, but for more than one, you need to use one of the previous techniques:** See the end of the Relationship Convention section of [Code First Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)

With conventions, you have to follow a convention that EF understands. I'm not absolutely sure, but try naming the ForeignKey properties like the navigation property with Id appended at the end, i.e.

```
public int ViewedWhoUserId { get; set; }
```

*NOTE: in fact, the EDM is constructed from a combination of the three techniques, so you can rely partially on conventions, for example for PKs, and on attributes or the Fluent API, for "fine-tuning" the model. But, as in this case, there are several differences on what you can do with the different techniques. Interestingly, on EF 6.1 you can [create your own custom conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469439) which can spare you writing some attributes and Fluent API configuraions.*

Comment: Tnx that worked (I added it for both properties). Can you just tell me when we are making relationship between objects like in my example do I actualy have to add `public ICollection<ApplicationUser> WhoViewedMyProfile { get; set; }` in my `User object`? Is it good practice or not necessary as now I didn't added it in `User` class?

Comment: The generated EDM is similar. The only difference is in the code side. If you add the property you can easyly navigate: for filtering on related properties, lazy loading, eager loading, adding related entties.... If not, you cannot navigate. So it basically depends on what you need to do in your code. This applies to both sides of the relationship, i.e. navigate from child to parent or from parent to children.

Comment: Note: there must be at least one navigation property, from child to parent or viceversa, to allow the DbContext to do "relationship fix-up" That's the only way to maintain the FKs and relationships between entities, to warranty that thins are consistent when calling SaveCahnges. Relationship fix-up means keeping in sync the relationships between entities and the FKs: if a child is added to a parent's navigation collection in a one-to-many relationship, DbContext will do the necessary to set the correct FK in the child, and to update the parent navigation property in the child (if it exist).